# Getting the perfect 3-column layout

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of a hard time trying to get the 3 column layout sorted.
This is my current HTML and css layout

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">C1</div>
    <div class="col">C2</div>
    <div class="col">C3</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
.row {
   width: 964px;
}

.row:last-child {
   margin: 0;
}

.row .col {
  width: 33.33%
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

The columns are basically of equal width using percentages of 33.33%.  Problem I have is that while the columns show up within the the row container, on the last column, there is a gap on the right margin.  Increasing the right margin pushes the last column to the next line.

How can I line up the columns so that they keep the same width, but for the first and last columns to not to have any margins (ie. no left margin on the first column and no right margin on the 3rd column).... Any ideas?

Thank you..

Comment: The answers will probably help you. But I thought I would chip in with suggesting taking a look at Bootstrap. It is a framework built around a grid system and would make short work of 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
.row .col:last-child
{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

this will do. but, don't forget to include it after **'.row.col'** style

Answer (score 0):

Use **%** instead of **px** here `margin-right: 10px;`

```
.col{
    width: 32%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.col:last-child{
    margin-right: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
.row{
display:table;
}
.col{
display:table-cell;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**:

```
.row{
   display:table;
   width:100%;

}
.col{
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:table-cell;
    width:33%;

}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nenoca7x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If your row is a fixed width (964px) then can't you just calculate the column widths that you want and put the margin as a left and right on column two?

Also, 964 doesn't divide by three so it's a bit of an odd choice - you'll always end up with rounding issues - I've changed it to 963px for the example below.

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">C1</div>
    <div class="col middle">C2</div>
    <div class="col">C3</div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.row .col {
  width: 321px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row .middle {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys, I ended up having to change the padding amount that my main site container was using. Once I had a width of 970px, I just borrowed a bit of css from Bootstrap to get the layout to display correctly.

End result being:

```
.row {
   margin-right: -15px;
   margin-left: -15px;    
}

.col {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33333333%;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 1px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-left: 15px;
}
```

That lines everything up perfect for me.